# Discord: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50001)

Tags: api, rest, discord

I tried to get a list of users through the API, but in response I got:

**Missing Access 403 Forbidden (error code: 50001)**

```
Request: https://discord.com/api/v9/guilds/{guild.id}/members;
```

And I was thrown out of my account, asking to verify my account.

At the same time, I accessed the server from the account that owns the server ...

MB is the fact that this is not a bot, but a live account?

Comment: Yes, using HTTP requests with user Discord accounts (user-botting) is against Discord TOS and they can eventually terminate your account. Create and use a bot account instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from comment:

> Yes, using HTTP requests with user Discord accounts (user-botting) is
> against Discord TOS and they can eventually terminate your account.
> Create and use a bot account instead.